# C Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2013

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/QU4NFQfN

Right now I've got it working but it is inefficient for being reasonably playable. I'm wanting to use the holder array I have (currently commented out) and I can only think to use a bunch of if statements to point the location of the grid array to a spot on the holder array. I need to use that to make the computer know how many spaces there are left using the noneTaken array. I need to also have the holder array to be usable and say when it is full but no one has won that the game is a draw.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: My question was how can I use the holder and noneTaken arrays to make the computer more efficient in playing against the human player and use the holder to help determine if a game is a draw.

Comment: Well, since the number of winning results is relatively small, you could create a lookup table and for every turn the computer makes, have it evaluate if it can make a winning move, if it can prevent a winning move, and then evaluate again for the player being two moves away. I don't feel like that is the most efficient way to do it, but the nice thing about tic-tac-toe is that in reality, with only a 3x3 array and only 8 ways to win (3 vertical, 3 horizontal, and 2 diagonal) brute force would actually work here.

Comment: Well, right now I have the win-able conditions coded, when the number of open spaces left gets to 2 or 3, the computer gets super slow since it is having to find a space it has not used already or my X's are not occupying